# no communication - ec2 instances with two interfaces in different subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, rhel7

I am stuck with the seemingly simple configuration on AWS - spin up VMs with 2 interfaces each, but each interface is in a different subnet and I can't communicate over secondary interfaces. Important piece: inside a VM I can communicate to all interfaces, between VMs in public/private zones - only over eth0.

Overview:

- VPC 10.20.0.0/16
- public zone:

  - management interface in subnet 10.20.0.0/20
  - production interface in subnet 10.20.48.0/20
- private zone:

  - management interface in subnet 10.20.16.0/20
  - production interface in subnet 10.20.64.0/20

Network ACLs are open/default, all interfaces have a security group which allows ping from 0.0.0.0/0

When I spin up VMs with RHEL7.5, I have this ec2-user-data script to bring up the secondary interface:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
EOF

ifup eth1e
```

Ping over the eth0 works without any issues, ping over eth1 hangs.

Here is routing on VM in private zone:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-20-8-62 ~]$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
    inet 10.20.8.62  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.20.15.255

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-8-62 ~]$ ifconfig eth1
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
    inet 10.20.53.116  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.20.63.255

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-8-62 ~]$ ip route
default via 10.20.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 10.20.48.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 101
10.20.0.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.8.62 metric 100
10.20.48.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.53.116 metric 101

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-8-62 ~]$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And the same for the VM in private zone:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-20-19-55 ~]$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
    inet 10.20.19.55  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.20.31.255

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-19-55 ~]$ ifconfig eth1
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
    inet 10.20.68.48  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.20.79.255

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-19-55 ~]$ ip route
default via 10.20.16.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 10.20.64.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 101
10.20.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.19.55 metric 100
10.20.64.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.68.48 metric 101

[ec2-user@ip-10-20-19-55 ~]$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Please let me know if I can provide some additional info, I spent too much time already trying to make it work. The reason for such a setup is our internal policies at the company. And I will need to make it work with 3 interfaces later on as well, so trying to understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: what about routes ?

Comment: @kintuparantu 10.20.0.0/16 local, it's default when you create any routing table within a vpc

Comment: I have terraform for this set up if anyone is willing to spend time and try to test it

Comment: how about using default settings for ```eth1``` ?

Comment: could you elaborate? upon the VM creation, eth1 is not configured so I thought the script I provided uses minimum possible configuration via dhcp

Comment: Had the same problem, follow this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-centos-rhel-secondary-interface/)

Answer (score 2):

As I've seen in AWS docummentation you need to add a different route table for your secondary network interface becasue in some way, AWS traffic from your secondary interface leaves with MAC from primary interface and this is not allowed.

*Both the primary and the secondary network interfaces are in different subnets, and by default there is only one routing table. Only one of the network interfaces is used to manage non-local subnet traffic. Any non-local subnet traffic that comes into the network interface that isn't configured with the default gateway tries to leave the instance using the interface that has the default gateway. This isn't allowed, because the secondary IP address doesn't belong to the Media Access Control (MAC) address of the primary network interface.*

Please follow this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-centos-rhel-secondary-interface/) to solve this issue.

I've tested it in CentOS 7 and it works.